# Why does my code not wait as per wait argument and why does it not return the Javascript rendered content?

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am trying to learn scrapy and splash to scrape efficiently from the web. I have installed scrapy, scrapy-splash and have splash running in a docker container. My code is below

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from pathlib import Path
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

max_price = "110000"
min_price = "65000"
region_code = "5E430"

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "propertySearch"

    def start_requests(self):
        url = "http://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/find.html?locationIdentifier=REGION%" + region_code + "&minBedrooms=2&maxPrice=" + max_price + "&minPrice=" + min_price + "&propertyTypes=detached" + \
        "%2Csemi-detached%2Cterraced&primaryDisplayPropertyType=houses&includeSSTC=false&mustHave=&dontShow=sharedOwnership%2Cretirement&furnishTypes=&keywords="
        yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse, args={'wait': 3})

    def parse(self, response):
        work_path = "C:/Users/Cristi/Desktop/Scrapy_ROI_work_area/"
        no_of_pages = response.xpath('//span[@class = "pagination-pageInfo"]')
        with open(Path(work_path, "test.txt"), 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        # with open(Path(work_path, "extract.txt"), 'wb') as g:
        #     g.write(no_of_pages)
        self.log('Saved file test.txt')

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(QuotesSpider)
process.start()
```

When I run it the console outputs the below if it is of any use.

```
2020-06-07 00:06:32 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.1.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
2020-06-07 00:06:32 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.1.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:20:19) [MSC v.1925 32 bit (Intel)], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020), cryptography 2.9.2, Platform Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
2020-06-07 00:06:32 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2020-06-07 00:06:32 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{}
2020-06-07 00:06:32 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 162ccfed8b528ac9
2020-06-07 00:06:32 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2020-06-07 00:06:32 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2020-06-07 00:06:32 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2020-06-07 00:06:32 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2020-06-07 00:06:32 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-06-07 00:06:32 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-06-07 00:06:32 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-06-07 00:06:32 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/find.html?locationIdentifier=REGION%5E430&minBedrooms=2&maxPrice=110000&minPrice=65000&propertyTypes=detached%2Csemi-detached%2Cterraced&primaryDisplayPropertyType=houses&includeSSTC=false&mustHave=&dontShow=sharedOwnership%2Cretirement&furnishTypes=&keywords=> from <GET http://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/find.html?locationIdentifier=REGION%5E430&minBedrooms=2&maxPrice=110000&minPrice=65000&propertyTypes=detached%2Csemi-detached%2Cterraced&primaryDisplayPropertyType=houses&includeSSTC=false&mustHave=&dontShow=sharedOwnership%2Cretirement&furnishTypes=&keywords=>
2020-06-07 00:06:33 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/find.html?locationIdentifier=REGION%5E430&minBedrooms=2&maxPrice=110000&minPrice=65000&propertyTypes=detached%2Csemi-detached%2Cterraced&primaryDisplayPropertyType=houses&includeSSTC=false&mustHave=&dontShow=sharedOwnership%2Cretirement&furnishTypes=&keywords=> (referer: None)
2020-06-07 00:06:33 [propertySearch] DEBUG: Saved file test.txt
2020-06-07 00:06:33 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-06-07 00:06:33 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 994,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 77255,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.429054,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 6, 23, 6, 33, 185514),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 6, 23, 6, 32, 756460)}
2020-06-07 00:06:33 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

The text file that it outputs only contains the bare HTML with none of the data that JavaScript would bring in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the documentation closely and found that first I needed to follow the scrapy project set-up process from [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) closely and then found very useful info [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html) about how to run my script from my IDE. It's working now.